# Using custom ghcjs fork with stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghcjs

I'm testing some of my own patches to ghcjs, and I was wondering how I can package it up to use with stack's fields, which seem to expect something like:

```
setup-info:
  ghcjs:
    source:
      ghcjs-0.2.1.9007019_ghc-8.0.1:
           url: http://ghcjs.tolysz.org/ghc-8.0-2017-02-05-lts-7.19-9007019.tar.gz
           sha1: d2cfc25f9cda32a25a87d9af68891b2186ee52f9
```

However, I'm unsure what format the `.tar.gz` file is expected to be in?  I tried simply compressing the repository in a `.tar.gz` file and it doesn't seem to recognize it.  What is actually expected to be in here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expects the output of "cabal sdist" / "stack sdist" run after building and booting your copy of ghcjs

Comment: just a note for future generations with the same question: do not run ghcjs-boot with --quick!  :)